# Filtering With a Variable Using Get-ADUser

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Currently I am pulling a list of emails from a SQL database, and storing these emails in a variable named `$emaildata`. I'm attempting to filter out any email in `$emaildata` from Active Directory. Right now no errors are popping up, but it's definitely not taking the emails out of the list that show up in the variable.

```
$ADUsers = Get-AdUser -Filter * -Properties SamAccountName, EmailAddress, Title, LastLogonDate, Name, GivenName, Surname, Company, Department, Country, EmployeeNumber, Enabled | Where {
    ($_.LastLogonDate -ge (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)) -and
    ($_.LastLogonDate -ne $null) -and
    ($_.EmailAddress -ne $null) -and
    ($_.EmployeeNumber -like '1000*') -and
    ($_.Enabled -eq 'True') -and
    ($_.EmailAddress -ne $emaildata)
} | Select GivenName, Surname, EmailAddress, Title
$ADUsers | Export-Csv C:\Lists\MainList.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

So it's this piece of the code that I'm attempting to work on.

```
($_.EmailAddress -ne $emaildata)
```

I've been looking for quite some time and everything I try hasn't worked, so I was hoping you guys would be able to help me out. Thanks!

The data in `$emaildata` looks like this

```
EmailAddress
------------
test1@test.com
test2@test.com
test3@test.com
test4@test.com
test5@test.com
```

Comment: Since `$emaildata` is likely an array, you will need to loop through them if you are using that in the filter. This is solely because the filter does not support collection operators like `-in` and `-notin`.

Comment: In your `where-object` script block, `($_.EmailAddress -notin $emaildata)` would be perfectly fine. You could move many of the conditions into the `-filter` if the filter supports the operator. `-ge`,`-ne`,`-eq`,`-like` should all be fine in the filter if you wanted them there.

Comment: What does $emaildata look like?

Comment: It just has multiple emails in it, so it's just a list of all emails in one column.

Comment: @AdminOfThings second comment should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$emailDataStringList = @( $emailData | Foreach-Object { return $_.EmailAddress.Trim() } )

.... | Where-Object { ...
    ($_.EmailAddress -ne $null) -and
    ($_.EmailAddress -ne '') -and
    ($emailDataStringList -notcontains $_.EmailAddress)
}
```

Your `$emailData` **is not** array of strings ( `[string[]]` ), it is array of objects with single property: `EmailAddress` ( according to your output ). There is many options to check if $adUser.EmailAddress is in list of $emailData, but simpliest is to convert array of objects to array of strings:

```
$emailDataStringList = @( $emailData | Foreach-Object { return $_.EmailAddress.Trim() } )
```

Sure there is a problem with `Enabled`: You compare it as string, you should compare it as bool:

```
$_.Enabled -eq $true
```

Also here may be a problem with `lastLogonDate`:
in `-and` expressions should FIRST check for `-ne $null` and only next step you can be sure there is a valid value to operate with. Otherwise you can hit strange behaviour with `$null -comparsionOperator [DateTime]`

```
($_.LastLogonDate -ne $null) -and
($_.LastLogonDate -ge (Get-Date).AddDays(-30))
```

Also, set variable `$dateToCheck = [DateTime]::Today.AddDays(-30)` and in `Where-Object` expression compare `$_.LastLogonDate -ge $dateToCheck`. This will be faster, powershell will compare `LastLogonDate` with predefined value and it will not calculate new `DateTime` each iteration.

According to `Get-ADUser` you can use `-LDAPFilter '(&(mail=*)(LastLogonTimeStamp=*))'` and throw away `-ne $null` checks and minimize memory usage and network usage. `LDAPFilter` and `Filter` are processed server-side

Next, please, take an **IMPORTANT** note: There is no attribute `LastLogonDate` attribute in AD. In `Get-AD*` it is dynamically calculated from `LastLogonTimeStamp`. `LastLogonTimeStamp` is NOT replicated immediately - it is stored only on DC, who processed user logon and replicated to another DC only if another DC's value differs for more than `ms-DS-Logon-Time-Sync-Interval` value ( 14 days default ). So, you should know about it: **`LastLogonDate` on your DC can be outdated for up to 14 days.** ( [See detailed explanation](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22461.understanding-the-ad-account-attributes-lastlogon-lastlogontimestamp-and-lastlogondate.aspx) ). You **MUST** check each DC in your forest if you really need accurate `LastLogonDate`. This is quite heavy and time-taking task.

Next, force `Get-ADUser` and `$... | Where { ... }` to be an array (use array conversion brackets `@()` ). Otherwise, you may get problems with your code when those expressions return single user or no users (`$null`). Enclosing to `@()` brackets, you guaranttee that your variable will be an array with 0, 1 or more elements.

Next, take a note please that you can hit timeout-like error here, because there is a timeout on `Get-AD*` cmdlets and if expression after pipe takes much time, the `Get-ADUser` will be terminated, pipe will be destroyed and you hit error.

Better store `Get-ADUser` results into a variable and filter in a separate expression:

```
$attributes = @('samaccountname', 'lastlogondate', '.....')    
$ADUsers = @( Get-ADUser -options.... -Properties $attributes )
$ADUsers = @( $ADUsers | Where-object { ... } )
$ADUsers | Select $attributes | Export-Csv -options...
```

P.S. Maybe there is whitespaces in your AD or Database. Use .Trim() in Where check:

```
$emailAddresses = @( $emailAddresses | Foreach-Object { return $_.Trim() } ) 
$... | Where { $emailAddresses -contains $_.EmailAddress.Trim()  }
```

---

your code will be like this:

```
$dateToCheck = [DateTime]::Today.AddDays(-30)
$emailDataStringList = @( $emailData | Foreach-Object { return $_.EmailAddress.Trim() } )
$ADUserProperties = @('SamAccountName', 'EmailAddress', 'Title', 'LastLogonDate', 'Name', 'GivenName', 'Surname', 'Company', 'Department', 'Country', 'EmployeeNumber', 'Enabled')
$ADUserList = @( Get-AdUser -LDAPFilter '(&(mail=*)(LastLogonTimeStamp=*)(employeeNumber=1000*))' -Properties $ADUserProperties )
$ADuserList = @( $ADUserList |
    Where-Object { $_.Enabled -eq $True} | # This is simplies check, this should be first
    Where-Object { $_.LastLogonDate -ge $dateToCheck } | 
    Where-Object { $emailDataStringList -notcontains $_.EmailAddress.Trim()}  | # This is hardest cpu-taking check, this should be last
    Select @('GivenName', 'Surname', 'EmailAddress', 'Title')
)
$ADuserList | Export-Csv C:\Lists\MainList.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

---

If you need more accurate `LastLogonDate`, you should get ADUsers from **EACH DC** in your envinronment. Something like this:

```
$DCList = @(get-addomaincontroller -filter *) 
$ADUserList = @( $DCList | ForEach-Object { Get-ADUser -Server $_.DNSName ... -properties @('SID', 'lastlogontimestamp', ...) } )
$ADUserList = @( $ADUserList | Sort-Object -Descending -Property 'lastlogontimestamp' | Sort-Object -Property 'SID' -Unique )
```

According to MS docs, `-Unique` takes **first** object in the list, so it should take the most accurate LastLogonDate for each user

Comment: And in your code you take `Name`, `Company`, `Department`, `Country`, and you do not export them or using in a code. Cleanup them. Also you do not need `EmployeeNumber` because you can check it in `-LDAPFilter` and do not load into powershell. Cleaning this out will be better.

Comment: The amount I learned from this is amazing. Thank you so much for the help.